# How to present 'no value' rather than error using date picker in PhP? Thanks

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to avoid showing following error if it returns no value using following code? I know there should be no value within some date range. But how to avoid showing following error and just return 'there is no data'?

[image]

This provide input data.

```
          if(isset($_GET["initialDate"])){

            $initialDate = $_GET["initialDate"];
            $finalDate = $_GET["finalDate"];

          }else{

            $initialDate = null;
            $finalDate = null;

          }

          
          $value1 = $_SESSION["relatedAccountID"];

          $answer = ControllerSales::ctrSalesDatesRange($initialDate, $finalDate, $value1);
```

This is controller function to use model.

```
    static public function ctrSalesDatesRange($initialDate, $finalDate, $value1){

        $table = "sales";

        $answer = ModelSales::mdlSalesDatesRange($table, $initialDate, $finalDate, $value1);

        return $answer;
        
    }
```

This is the model to get results.

```
    static public function mdlSalesDatesRange($table, $initialDate, $finalDate, $value1){

        if($initialDate == null){

            $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE relatedAccountID = $value1 ORDER BY id ASC");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll(); 


        }else if($initialDate == $finalDate){

            $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE relatedAccountID = $value1 AND saleDate like '%$finalDate%'");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":saleDate", $finalDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }else{

            $actualDate = new DateTime();
            $actualDate ->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
            $actualDatePlusOne = $actualDate->format("Y-m-d");

            $finalDate2 = new DateTime($finalDate);
            $finalDate2 ->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
            $finalDatePlusOne = $finalDate2->format("Y-m-d");

            if($finalDatePlusOne == $actualDatePlusOne){

                $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (relatedAccountID = $value1) AND (saleDate BETWEEN '$initialDate' AND '$finalDatePlusOne')");

            }else{


                $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (relatedAccountID = $value1) AND (saleDate BETWEEN '$initialDate' AND '$finalDate')");

            }
        
            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();


        }

    }
```

With this error I have to refresh the web page to go back, which is quite uncovinent?

Comment: You're trying to bind parameters, but you've already SQL injected and there are no parameters to bind to. Hint: Use `:initialDate` instead. **NEVER** put raw data in SQL strings.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean replace '$initialDate' with initialDate''? Then add $stmt -> bindParam(":initialDate", $initialDate, PDO::PARAM_STR)?

Comment: That's much better, yes. You should be doing that with all your data parameters. It's the proper, and only really safe way to do it. Note that with PDO you can also do a sort of lazy `execute(':initialDate' => $initialDate)` as well if you're not too fussed about the types.

Comment: It looks like it is not working with $stmt -> bindParam(":initialDate", $initialDate, PDO::PARAM_STR). I got all error with this code? I put this code behind $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (relatedAccountID = $value1) AND (saleDate BETWEEN initialDate AND '$finalDatePlusOne')");